# Как сделать, чтобы при выборе цвета из comboBox менялcя цвет картинки/BackgroundImage?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli, combobox

[image: Пример]

```
private: System::Void pictureBox7_Click(System::Object^  sender, 
System::EventArgs^  e) {
         switch (comboBox1->SelectedIndex)
         {
         case 0: pictureBox7->BackgroundImage    ;break ;
         case 1: pictureBox7->BackgroundImage    ;break ;
         ...
         }

     }
```

Что надо написать в коде, чтобы при выборе первой позиции из comboBox в pictureBox был там красный цвет или вставить изображение с этим цветом. Как это записать в коде?

Comment: Чувствую, что курсовую я не напишу :)
Разве нет никакого другого выхода? Взять какой то другой объект, чтобы было наглядное изменение?

Comment: Я прикрепляла код, и скрин. ComboBox в Items заполнен цветами радуги.

Comment: Как данные попадают в комбобокс: вручную или через привязку данных? От этого зависит ответ.

Comment: Вручную вписывала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навешиваете на комбобокс обработчик события `SelectedIndexChanged`. В нём пишете примерно такой код:

```
private: System::Void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    switch (comboBox1->SelectedIndex)
    {
    case 0: pictureBox1->BackColor = Color::Red; break;
    case 1: pictureBox1->BackColor = Color::Green; break;
    case 2: pictureBox1->BackColor = Color::Blue; break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Вместо предопределённых цветов `Color::Red` и т. п. можно задать свои собственные:

```
Color::FromArgb(200, 200, 100);
```

Можно вместо индексов использовать строковые значения, занесенные в комбобокс:

```
String^ color = comboBox1->SelectedItem->ToString();

if (color == "Красный")
    pictureBox1->BackColor = Color::Red;
else if (color == "Зеленый")
    pictureBox1->BackColor = Color::Green;
else if (color == "Синий")
    pictureBox1->BackColor = Color::Blue;
```

Оператор `switch` с типом `String` использовать нельзя, поэтому `if`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!